# Convert comma seperated string to json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a comma seperated string value like

> 100,140

i need to convert that into a json string. that should be like

> {"person":[{"id":"100"},{"id":"140"}]}

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Please provide any more details about what you are using (frameworks/libraries/techniques). Now we don't know what you exactly want to do.

Comment: i want to pass the result as a query string to an api

Comment: input is a set of ids.

Comment: Are you using any libraries yet? jQuery, plain javascript? Or do you want this to be on your serverside with Java or C# for instance. Based on you question we cannot see what you are trying to accomplish. We need the already used techniques to help you with a proper answer. As you can see you will already get different answers, but I can give you several answers on this question in different programming languages. So that's why we need more input or already existing code snippets.

Comment: I see you added the C#, json and asp.net-mvc which helps us better! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering you use a [Json.net library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), I suggest first to split your string to an array by comma andserialize it to a string:

```
var ids = "100,140".Split(',');
var personsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { person = ids.Select(x => new { id = x }).ToList()});
```

In my example, i serialize a dynamic type, but you can implement your custom class Person with ids array.

Comment: I am using **Newtonsoft.json**. Let me try this solution.

Answer (score 1):

first split your string and store in an array.
Then convert your strings to jsonObjects.
Add jsonobjects to jsonarray.
follow the below code . it's working.

```
        String split = "100,140";
        String[] datas = split.split(",");
        JsonArray jsonArry = new JsonArray();
        for (String data : datas)
        {
            JsonObject jsonobj = new JsonObject();
            jsonobj.addProperty("id",data);
            //jsonobj.SetNamedValue("id", JsonValue.CreateStringValue(data));
            jsonArry.add(jsonobj);
        }
        JsonObject jsonobj2 = new JsonObject();
        //jsonobj2.SetNamedValue("person", jsonArry);
        jsonobj2.addProperty("person", jsonArry);

        //also you can convert the jsonobject to string.
        String jsonString = jsonobj2.ToString();
```

Comment: the answer with JsonArray and JsonObject is correct. Because the OP han't said anything about Person Class Model.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you have Json serialiser in conrollers. Just create model that describes your json in your case it will be:

```
    public class Model
    {
        public IEnumerable<Person> person { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

And then in your controller you are able to do this:

```
    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var str = "100,140"; // your string
        Model model = new Model();
        //parse string to model
        model.person = str.Split(',').Select(x => new Person { id = Convert.ToInt32(x) });
        //serialize to json
        return Json(model);
    }
```