# Convert string from get method to a valid json c#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to put a string on a json array from get but the JArray.Parse is failing because the string is not a valid json object in the first place. How do I convert a comma delimited string to json?

The input is like

```
34520,63631,45628
```

The code is like below;

```
public static string GetLocationInZips(string strZipCodes)
        {
            JArray jarrZipCodes = new JArray();
            JObject response = new JObject();

            try
            {
                jarrZipCodes = JArray.Parse(strZipCodes);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                response["success"] = false;
                response["error"] = "Failed to serialize zip code array, please check and try again";
                response["exception"] = ex.ToString();

                return response.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are u wanna an array or object or what?

Comment: Well if the code lines can be reduced can the input I mentioned be placed directly as a json array? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use JArray. Use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strZipCodes.Split(','))` since you want a JSON array from string array. If you cannot use `JsonConvert` from `NewtonSoft.JSON`, use `JavascriptSerializer`.

```
  //Call below function like 

 var jsonZipCodes = GetLocationInZips("34520,63631,45628");

  public static string GetLocationInZips(string strZipCodes)
    {
        string jarrZipCodes = string.Empty;
        JObject response = new JObject();

        try
        {

     //       jarrZipCodes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strZipCodes.Split(','));
           jarrZipCodes = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(strZipCodes.Split(','));
            return jarrZipCodes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response["success"] = false;
            response["error"] = "Failed to serialize zip code array, please check and try again";
            response["exception"] = ex.ToString();

            return response.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: for solution 1 since the input varies can i declare another string and have my input variable wrapped like below
string ziplist = "[{strZipCodes}]";

Comment: Yes, like this string ziplist = "[all_comma_separated_zip_codes_here]"

Comment: this resulted to an exception
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path

Comment: FIrst one or second one. Can you share the ziplist variable?

Comment: the ziplist content is the one from the GetLocationsZips which is the string strZipCodes variable

Comment: Do one thing. Do not return JArray Object. Inside your function, just use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strZipCodes.Split(',')) only, and result would be conversion of comma delimited string to json as you require.

Comment: See the changed solution 2 above.

Comment: Solution changed, check now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Json.net library for this. You can split the values into an array with the `Split()` function to deal with each value separately.

Then use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to convert to JSON.

See [Convert comma seperated string to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560733/convert-comma-seperated-string-to-json) for a great example

Comment: cant use JsonConvert any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string to get an array and use `JArray.FromObject` like this:

```
string testInput = "34520,63631,45628";
JArray array = JArray.FromObject(testInput.Split(','));
```

Comment: this resulted to an error exception below;
System.ArgumentException: Object serialized to String. JArray instance expected

Comment: Sorry, I posted a little too fast before leaving.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Amit below is the final working solution.

```
public static string GetLocationInZips(string strZipCodes)
        {
            JArray jarrZipCodes = new JArray();
            string jarrZipCode = string.Empty;
            JObject response = new JObject();

            jarrZipCode = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strZipCodes.Split(','));

            try
            {
                jarrZipCodes = JArray.Parse(jarrZipCode);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                response["success"] = false;
                response["error"] = "Failed to serialize zip code array, please check and try again";
                response["exception"] = ex.ToString();

                return response.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Amit solution is correct. This one is not. You're missing a `return` statement and your `jarrZipCodes ` is a `JArray` and not a `string`.